# Downloading a textfile to the server's memory but doesn't work (html, php)

Tags: php, html

I'm doing work for my school about programming a web page, and I would like to have a page where once the user put some data in a textfile, this automatically downloads to where I want in my computer. My page is in HTML but I'm trying to do this action in PHP. 
The problem is, that I can't make the code run even though I have checked various times and everything should be fine. What do I have to do to solve this problem?

Thanks :D

This is the main page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Recuperació i actualització de contrasenyes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content=" Aquest lloc és un espai on es pot recuperar les contrasenyes dels clients.">
    <meta name="keyboards" content="Banc, Contrasesnyes, Clients, Manianet" >
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function animaMissatge() {
                $("missatgeError").animate{
                    opacity: 0.25,
                    left: "+=50",
                    height:"toggle"
                }, 1500, function(){}
            };
            function comprovaFormulari() {
                var pmissatge = document.getElementById("missatgeError")
                var nom = document.getElementById("usuari").value;
                if (nom == "") {
                    pmissatge.innerHTML = "Has d'introduir l'usuari";
                }
                else {
                    var comentari = document.getElementById("contrasenya").value;
                    if (comentari == "") {
                        pmissatge.innerHTML = "Has d'introduir la contrasenya";
                    }
                    else{
                        var form = document.getElementById("blog.txt");
                        form.submit();
                    }                           }
                }

                return false;
            }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        Pàgina web oficial del banc manianetià. Les seves dades estan segures amb nosaltres!
    </nav>
</header>
<article>
<h1 id="h1_title">
Actualització de contrasenya
</h1>
<section id="section_1">
<div id="column_1">
    <p>
    A través d'aquesta pàgina web, podreu recuperar o actualitzar la vostra contrasenya de manera gratuita i totalment fiable. Aixi, podreu iniciar sessió més cómodament i sense cap problema.
    </p>
</div>
    <h3>
    Inserti aqui les seves dades:
    </h3>
</section>

<section>
        <form method="post" action="prova.php">
            <p>Usuari:<input type="text" name="usuari" id="usuari"></p>
            <p>Contrasenya:<input type="text" name="contrasenya" id="contrasenya"></p>
            <input type="button" value="envia" name="envia" onclick="comprovaFormulari();">
            <input type="button" value="anima" name="anima" onclick="animaMissatge()">
        </form>
    <p id="missaatgeError">
    </p>
</section>

<section>
    <p>Gràcies a la vostra fidelització, hem aconseguit:</p>
        <ul id="llista_1">
            <li> Un banc segur, fiable i compromés amb els clients. </li>
            <li> Noves hipoteques amb un 0% d'interessos. </li>
            <li> Premi a la millor pàgina web de l'any per l'associació "El Tribunal de Recerca" </li>
        </ul>
</section>B0
<footer id="footer_1">
    <p> <i> Si vol més informació, faci click <a href="https://www.lescorts.manyanet.org/"><u>aqui</u></a></i> </p>
</footer>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is prova.php

```
 <?php
    $fitxer = "blog.txt";
    $nom = $_GET["usuari"];
    $msg = $_GET["contrasenya"];

    file_put_contents($fitxer, $nom.": ".$msg,"</br", FILE_APPEND);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Comentaris enviats!</h1>
<p> Gràcies per la teva participació!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're using the wrong method and you have a syntax error in `"</br"`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner why would the `</br` be a syntax error? It's a string. Do you mean the comma before it?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan the `</br` should be `<br>` or `<br/>` and will never work once they start echoing that later on. Plus, it's also an invalid tag method.

Comment: Please provide a *minimal* example of what is not working.

Comment: Then what's the correct method? I would like to fix this problem, but I'm not very experienced as you can see ^^

Comment: Please share more details - what **exactly** is not working? What is all that JS code doing? For example, `var form = document.getElementById("blog.txt");` - where is that element? You don't use any HTML element with `id="blog.txt"` in the markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was going to just edit the answer, but this requires a full rewrite.

There were multiple errors, all the way through the code. I'll start from the top:

### Main Page

1. You never imported jQuery. You use jQuery for the animation, but never required it.
2. There were multiple syntax errors within the `animaMissatge` function.
3. The form that you were calling in the `comprovaFormulari` function didn't exist. I replaced it with the real one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Recuperació i actualització de contrasenyes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content=" Aquest lloc és un espai on es pot recuperar les contrasenyes dels clients.">
    <meta name="keyboards" content="Banc, Contrasesnyes, Clients, Manianet" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function animaMissatge() {
          $("missatgeError").animate({
              opacity: 0.25,
              left: "+=50",
              height:"toggle"
          }, 1500);
      }
      function comprovaFormulari() {
          var pmissatge = document.getElementById("missatgeError")
          var nom = document.getElementById("usuari").value;
          if (nom == "") {
              pmissatge.innerHTML = "Has d'introduir l'usuari";
          }
          else {
              var comentari = document.getElementById("contrasenya").value;
              if (comentari == "") {
                  pmissatge.innerHTML = "Has d'introduir la contrasenya";
              }
              else{
                  var form = document.getElementById("msForm");
                  form.submit();
              }                           
          }
          return false;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        Pàgina web oficial del banc manianetià. Les seves dades estan segures amb nosaltres!
      </nav>
    </header>
    <article>
      <h1 id="h1_title">Actualització de contrasenya</h1>
      <section id="section_1">
        <div id="column_1">
          <p>A través d'aquesta pàgina web, podreu recuperar o actualitzar la vostra contrasenya de manera gratuita i totalment fiable. Aixi, podreu iniciar sessió més cómodament i sense cap problema.</p>
        </div>
        <h3>Inserti aqui les seves dades:</h3>
      </section>
      <section>
        <form method="post" action="prova.php" id="msForm">
          <p>Usuari:<input type="text" name="usuari" id="usuari"></p>
          <p>Contrasenya:<input type="text" name="contrasenya" id="contrasenya"></p>
          <input type="button" value="envia" name="envia" onclick="comprovaFormulari();">
          <input type="button" value="anima" name="anima" onclick="animaMissatge()">
        </form>
        <p id="missaatgeError"></p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p>Gràcies a la vostra fidelització, hem aconseguit:</p>
        <ul id="llista_1">
          <li> Un banc segur, fiable i compromés amb els clients. </li>
          <li> Noves hipoteques amb un 0% d'interessos. </li>
          <li> Premi a la millor pàgina web de l'any per l'associació "El Tribunal de Recerca" </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <footer id="footer_1">
        <p> <i>Si vol més informació, faci click <a href="https://www.lescorts.manyanet.org/"><u>aqui</u></a></i> </p>
      </footer>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

### prova.php

There were multiple errors in here too.

1. The two variables you named, `$nom` and `$msg`, were calling `$_GET` variables. Since they were sent through a form, they are `$_POST` variables.
2. The `file_put_contents` function was badly written. I replaced the `</br` with a `\n`, and put the content into one pair of quotes.

```
<?php
    $fitxer = "blog.txt";
    $nom = $_POST["usuari"];
    $msg = $_POST["contrasenya"];

    file_put_contents($fitxer, "$nom: $msg\n", FILE_APPEND);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Comentaris enviats!</h1>
<p> Gràcies per la teva participació!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd be glad to upvote this, but I have none left for the moment. I do have to mention though that if they're wanting line breaks between each line, they are using the wrong tag for this. It should be `\n` (if on a \*NIX/MACOS) OS and not `<br>`. Or `PHP_EOL` being cross-platform.

Comment: Then there is the form's method being "post" and they're using GET arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but it still doesn't work. I think the function comprovaformulari() is not working, cause every time I press the button "envia" it doesn't move me to the other page (the php one) or send me any errors if there's nothing written there.In few words, the button "envia" doesn't work when clicking it. If you can find the error I would love you, this have driving me out for over 2 weeks now ^^'.

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: Ok, I found lots and lots of errors, I'm going to go through and fix them. Once I'm done, I'll post it here

Comment: Also, are you from Barcelona?

Comment: Yes I am ^^'. Did you know it for the language used? Btw right now I'm going to see if it works. In case it does, you've made my day :D

Comment: Yes. Força Barça! :)

Comment: It does definitely work. Thank you very much for everything! <3 Força Barça!